# Show that the integral of a non-negative measurable function $f$ is the infimum of the integral of lower semi-continuous functions greater than $f$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space which is $\sigma$-compact, and $\mu$ be a Randon measure. For any non-negative Borel measuralbe function $f$, show shat
$$\int_X f\,d\mu=\inf\{\int_X g\,d\mu:g\geq f;g\ \text{lower semi-continuous}\}.$$
I don't know how to get started, the integral of $f$ is defined by supremum, but  what we need to show is infimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $f$ is the limit of an increasing sequence of non-negative simple functions. So $f$ is the sum of a series of non-negative simple functions, hence $$f=\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j\chi_{E_j},$$with each $a_j>0$.

Say $V_j$ is an open set with $E_j\subset V_j$, and let $$g=\sum_ja_j\chi_{V_j}.$$Then $g\ge f$. And $g$ is lsc: Suppose $g(x)>\alpha$. Then there exists $n$ so that $g_n(x)=\sum_{j=1}^na_j\chi_{V_j}(x)>\alpha$, and hence $g\ge g_n>\alpha$ on $\bigcap_{j=1}^nV_j$, a neighborhood of $x$.

If $\int f=\infty$ we're done. Suppose that $\int f<\infty$, and let $\epsilon>0$. We can choose $V_j$ so that $$\mu(V_j)<\mu(E_j)+\frac{\epsilon}{2^ja_j},$$implying that $$\int g<\epsilon+\int f.$$

Comment: Nice answer, the key ingredient is to express $f$  as a series of indicator functions.